# Python, Scrapy Pipeline csv out problem, error in for loop

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working Google search crawling using scrapy. This is the code and it works well to get search results.

GoogleBot.py:

```
class GoogleBotsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'GoogleScrapyBot'
allowed_domains = ['google.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/search?q=apple&hl=en&rlz=&start=0']

def parse(self, response):
    item = {}
    all_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]')
    for page in all_page:
        title = page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/h3/div/text()').extract()
        link = page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/@href').extract()
        for title, link in zip(title, link):
            print(title)
            print(link.lstrip("/url?q="))
```

[image]

My next step is use "pipeline" on Scrapy to save a csv file for results.
Here is the code that I have written so far.

setting.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'GoogleScrapy.pipelines.GooglePipeline': 300,}
```

pipelines.py:

```
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter  
class GooglePipeline(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.file = open("GoogleSearchResult.csv", 'wb')
    self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file, encoding='utf-8')
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

  def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    self.file.close()

  def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
    return item
```

This is modified my spider code.

GoogleBot.py:

```
def parse(self, response):
item = {}
all_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]')
for page in all_page:
    item['title'] = page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/h3/div/text()').extract()
    item['link'] = page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/@href').extract()
    for title, link in zip(title, link):
        print(title)
        print(link.lstrip("/url?q="))
yield item
```

It has error where in:

```
for title, link in zip(title, link):
    print(title)
    print(link.lstrip("/url?q="))
```

I get this error:

> for title, link in zip(title, link):
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'title' referenced before assignment

Comment: Did you mean `zip(item["title"], item["link"])`?

Comment: @paul Thanks ,but when I use zip(item["title"], item["link"]), the output(csv) is writing list itself. I'd like to create csv, coulm1-> title / coulm2 -> link for result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working output according to your comment.

```
import scrapy

class GoogleBotsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'GoogleScrapyBot'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/search?q=apple&hl=en&rlz=&start=0']


    def parse(self, response):
       
        all_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]')
        for page in all_page:
            
                titles = page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/h3/div//text()').extract()
                for title in titles:

                    links = page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/@href').extract() 
                    for link in links:
                        item={
                            'Title': title,
                            'Link':link
                            }
                        yield item
```

Comment: Thank you. When I run this code, I get a csv with title,link column. However, it gets 12 items duplicated. How to fix it?

Comment: This fix is not related with your question. use " dont_filter =True"

Comment: Oh, I see. But I have never been use this option "dont_filter =True" before, so where do I put this option on your reply code?